# Why it's not recommended to use IDs in wxPython?

Tags: wxpython

I read this [Style Guide for wxPython code](https://wiki.wxpython.org/wxPython%20Style%20Guide) which says:

```
3. Don't use IDs. There is very rarely a good reason to use them.
```

I've also seen a lot of `wx.ID_ANY` in application code.

Questions:

1. Why it's not recommended to use IDs?
2. Why doesn't the library simply hide IDs in the API if they shouldn't be used anyway?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want to use hard-coded IDs because there are some that are reserved by wxPython itself. This is why we have `wx.ID_ANY`. This allows wxPython to grab an unused ID, which prevents collisions, which also prevents hard to find bugs.

Note that using `wx.NewId` is now deprecated and you should use `wx.Window.NewControlId()` in wxPython 4.

Comment: Thank you. I think that guide may better phase it as *Don't use **hard-coded** IDs* because `wx.ID_ANY` will still generate an ID.

Comment: BTW: You mentioned that `wx.NewId` is [deprecated](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.functions.html#wx.NewId). However, we can still use `wx.ID_ANY`, which isn't deprecated, right?

Comment: @Cyker wx.ID_ANY is -1 which wxPython will use to pick up the next free Id. Also see `wx.NewIdRef()` wx.NewIdRef(count=1)
Reserves a new Window ID (or range of WindowIDs) and returns a wx.WindowIDRef object (or list of them) that will help manage the reservation of that ID.

This function is intended to be a drop-in replacement of the old and deprecated wx.NewId function, with the added benefit that the ID should never conflict with an in-use ID or other IDs generated by this function. https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.functions.html#wx.NewIdRef